# Rotatexbox is not working with TEX4ht in a picture tabular enviroment

Tags: tex4ht

I'm trying to generate HTML from TeX and I want the tables to be converted into images. Here follows a simples example showing the problem I found when I have a rotated element in the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\sr}{\rule[0.45cm]{0pt}{0.25cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Test table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll|c|c|l}
    \cline{3-4}&    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{actual class}   &  \\  \cline{3-4} &   & cat & dog  & \\   \cline{1-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\parbox[t]{4mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[]{90}{\centering predicted}}}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[]{90}{\centering \ cat\ } \sr}                   & 5 & 2  &  \\ \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[]{90}{\centering \ dog\ } \sr} & 3  & 3 &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The table generated in PDF version is displayed below:

[image: table in the resulting PDF file]

I've tried to use `\Picture*{} ... \EndPicture` to convert the table into an image. Therefore, I created the config file `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,charset=utf-8,fn-in}
\begin{document}  
\ConfigureEnv{table}
    {\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\EndPreamble
```

and compiled the HTML using

```
htlatex example "myconfig2.cfg, xhtml, charset=utf-8, fn-in" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

The resulting image was

[image: resulting image created by htlatex]

How could I fix it?

Comment: converting tables to images should be a last resort, that makes horrible html pages????

Comment: probably not related but `\centering` does nothing in `\rotatebox[]{90}{\centering predicted}}` `\centering` specifies alignment of _paragraphs` but `\rotatebox` is like `\mbox` and does not allow paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a build in support for pictorial tables in TeX4ht, using the `pic-tabular` option. You don't need to use custom configurations for that. See [list of options](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html) for some other possibilities.

You also should use `make4ht` instead of `htlatex`, as it produces HTML 5 output in UTF-8 encoding by default. It also post-process the generated HTML code and fixes some issues that are not easily fixable otherwise.

So, you can compile your document using:

```
make4ht example "pic-tabular,svg,fn-in"
```

Note that I used the `svg` option. It is because `dvipng` has problem with the DVI code in this particular case, maybe because of `\rotatebox`. `svg` options requires conversion using `dvisvgm` and it works nicely:

[image]

As David Carlisle said, it is better to not convert tables to images. In this particular case, the rotated text don't come nicely. The text is placed over table lines. But do you really need rotated cells in HTML? I would just output it in the normal direction. It can be done using the following `.cfg` file, `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\renewcommand\rotatebox[3][]{#3}
\renewcommand\sr{}
\Css{\#TBL-1 \#TBL-1-5g{border:none;}}
\Css{\#TBL-1 \#TBL-1-1g{border:none;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It redefines `\rotatebox` to just print the text, without any rotation.

Note these lines:

```
\Css{\#TBL-1 \#TBL-1-5g{border:none;}}
\Css{\#TBL-1 \#TBL-1-1g{border:none;}}
```

It removes spurious vertical lines in the table.

Compile using

```
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg example "fn-in"
```

This is the resulting HTML:

[image]

Comment: The first solution did almost work as shown by @michal-h21. In the caption I got "**TableÂ 1:** Test table" instead.

Comment: Maybe @david-carlisle is right, I should stick with HTML table, but is it possible to generate the table image as well? I'm gonna feed the HTML in Redalyc system, and they also require a print of the tables.

Comment: @LEo it seems like if your document isn't rendered as UTF-8. Maybe try to add explicit `-u` option to `make4ht`

Comment: @michal-h21 it did work in the example... other document, with characters diacritical marks (like áãçóõ) it is creating new paragraphs, but just for the text in the abstract  ```<p><span class='cmr-9'>ç</span></p>
<p><span class='cmr-9'>ã</span></p>
<p><span class='cmr-9'>o de</span></p> ```

Comment: I guess it is some sort of incompatibility with the class ```abntex2```.

Comment: @LEo yes, this can happen when some configuration is missing. It would be best if you could post a new question that shows this issue.

Comment: @micha-h21 I've posted it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579888/problem-when-using-abntex2-class-and-make4ht