# problem when using abnTEX2 class and make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

When creating HTML using `make4ht` for a document using the class `abnTEX2`, the generated document has a new paragraph for each diacritical marks in the abstract (only).

An example file follows:

```
\documentclass[brazil,article]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\title{Um apólogo}
\author{Machado de Assis}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Machado de Assis, um homem do século XIX, escreveu o conto
\textit{Um apólogo} abaixo transcrito.
\end{abstract}

Era uma vez uma agulha, que disse a um novelo de linha:

-- Por que está você com esse ar, toda cheia de si, toda
enrolada, para fingir que vale alguma coisa neste mundo?

-- Deixe-me, senhora.

-- Que a deixe? Que a deixe, por quê? Porque lhe digo que
está com um ar insuportável? Repito que sim, e falarei sempre
que me der na cabeça.
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `make4ht -u example` I get some errors in `\maketitle` (without maketitle there is no error)

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./example.tex    7    Undefined control sequence.
```

and the result is

[image: document using abnTEX2 generated by make4ht]

What's happening in *abstract*? How to fix it?

Comment: I get an error also with `pdflatex` it seems that the `\tituloestrangeiro{An apologist}` must be used. With this change, I can compile document without errors with both `pdflatex` and `make4ht`. It doesn't fix the abstract issue, it is another problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one small issue with your example. I get an error unless I provide the `\tituloestrangeiro` command. I don't know if it is required by `abntex2`, but from reading of it's sources it seems that it is required when you use the `article` document class option. So I've added the following command after `\title` and it fixed this issue:

```
\tituloestrangeiro{An apologist}
```

Now regarding the lines broken on accented characters. This is in fact introduced by `make4hth`. It makes paragraph for every inline element that is placed directly in the `<body> element, so it is outside paragraph or other block element. It does it in order to produce valid HTML. Now TeX4ht produces extra` ` element for every accented character in your abstract, but they are not placed inside paragraph, so this mechanism makes one for each one.

To fix this, we must configure `abstract` environment to produce better output. This can be done using the following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure the abtract environment to produce the <section> element
\ConfigureEnv{abstract}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<section role="doc-abstract" class="abstract">\Hnewline}} 
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</section>}}{}{}
% we want to get rid of the center environment used around the abstract title
% we also introduce a <h3> element for the title
\newenvironment{dummyabstracttitle}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h3 class="abstracttitle">}}{\HCode{</h3>}\par\noindent}
% use our dummy environment to insert tags around the abstract title
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{dummyabstracttitle}
% get rid of all extra <span> elements introduced by smaller font size
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont}
% style the abstract
\Css{.abstract{margin:1em;font-size:0.9rem;}}
\Css{.abstracttitle{text-align:center;margin-bottom:1em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I will describe it a bit:

```
\ConfigureEnv{abstract}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<section role="doc-abstract" class="abstract">\Hnewline}} 
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</section>}}{}{}
```

This configures the `abstract` environment to use the `<section>` element around it's contents.

The abstract title inserted by the class inserts lot of formatting commands to the HTML code, which is really unnecessary. As `abntex2` is based on Memoir, we can provide a custom environment to format the title. We do lot of stuff in this environment:

```
\newenvironment{dummyabstracttitle}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h3 class="abstracttitle">}}{\HCode{</h3>}\par\noindent}
```

The `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` commands close potentials opened paragraphs before we insert the `<h3>` tag. `\par\noindent` after the end starts a new paragraph, to ensure that the abstract text is inside it.

To get rid most of the `<span>` elements, which are requested by the fact that a smaller font is used for the abstract contents, we just redefine the commands that choose the abstract font to use the normal font:

```
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont}
```

The final document looks like this:

[image]